# Float right but keep logical order

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup, which produces a paragraph with an image to the right.

```
<p>
  <div style="float: right;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50"/>
    <div>Caption</div>
  </div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Morbi commodo nibh a sem ornare porttitor. 
Maecenas ultrices tristique est in interdum. 
</p>
```

This floats the image to the right, but also allows the text to wrap around the image.

Because I work with responsive design I wondered if there was any way I could keep the following formatting

[image: Formatting]

but put the coding in 'logical order' ie;

```
<p>text
<div>
    <img>
    {caption}
```

Comment: You should not be putting block elements like divs inside paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
text-align: left;
```

for the caption `div`?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be putting block elements like divs inside paragraphs and this would seem to be an ideal use of a `figure` and `figcaption` element.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/LA5UP/6/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <p>
        <figure style="float: right;">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50"/>
            <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam obcaecati excepturi consequuntur sed quas sapiente eaque hic error culpa enim nulla laudantium optio numquam veritatis dolorem repellendus corporis cum itaque eligendi nam temporibus officiis assumenda. Quas quod quis magni minus nesciunt sequi et labore aspernatur
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width:500px;
}

figure {
    float:right;
    border:1px solid grey;
}

figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}
```